# How do I interactively select region of interests on vtk?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I am using vtk with QT. Currently I read a series of Dicom Images using `vtkDicomImageReader` and visualize them with `vtkImageViewer2` into slices.

Now I want to use mouse to pick some points and generate a closed curve on a 2D image slice, can anyone suggests what vtk method or class might be help?

Comment: Have you tried using vtk widgets? take a look at `vtkImageTracerWidget`

Comment: I finally use `vtkContourWidget`, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally use `vtkContourWidget` class for points selection.
[This](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Widgets/ContourWidget) is a basic sample for using `vtkContourWidget` and [this](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkContourRepresentation.html) is the documentation of this class.

In my work, `vtkContourWidget` is binded with a `vtkImageViewer2` using `SetInteractor` method. After binding it, I could use mouse click to pick some points and generate a contour line.

Comment: The link to the example no longer works.  It leads to a default page.